# Lookup table in TensorFlow with key is string and value is list of strings

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I would like to generate a Lookup table in TensorFlow with key is string and value is list of strings. But it seems currently no classes in tf.lookup support this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think there is an implementation for exactly that use case, but you can try combining `tf.lookup.StaticHashTable` and `tf.gather` to create your own custom lookup table. You just need to make sure that your keys and string lists are in the correct order. For example, key `a` corresponds to the first string list, key `b` corresponds to the second string list and so on. Here is a working example:

```
class TensorLookup:
  def __init__(self, keys, strings):
    self.keys = keys
    self.strings = strings
    self.table = tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(
    tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(self.keys, tf.range(tf.shape(self.keys)[0])),
    default_value=-1)
  
  def lookup(self, key):
    index = self.table.lookup(key)
    return tf.cond(tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(index, -1)), lambda: tf.constant(['']), lambda: tf.gather(self.strings, index))

keys = tf.constant(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
strings = tf.ragged.constant([['fish', 'eating', 'cats'], 
                              ['cats', 'everywhere'], 
                              ['you', 'are', 'a', 'fine', 'lad'], 
                              ['a', 'mountain', 'over', 'there'],
                              ['bravo', 'at', 'charlie'] 
                              ])

tensor_dict = TensorLookup(keys = keys, strings = strings)

print(tensor_dict.lookup(tf.constant('a')))
print(tensor_dict.lookup(tf.constant('b')))
print(tensor_dict.lookup(tf.constant('c')))
print(tensor_dict.lookup(tf.constant('r'))) # expected empty value since the r key does not exist
```

```
tf.Tensor([b'fish' b'eating' b'cats'], shape=(3,), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor([b'cats' b'everywhere'], shape=(2,), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor([b'you' b'are' b'a' b'fine' b'lad'], shape=(5,), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor([b''], shape=(1,), dtype=string)
```

I intentionally use a ragged tensor to accommodate different lengths of string lists.

Comment: What if I have to pass an array of keys in lookup call? Specifically if I want to call: 
`print(tensor_dict.lookup(tf.constant(['a', 'r')]))` ,  will it work?

Comment: You will have to make sure the keys are also indexed, similar to the values